# Loop Macro for Pivot Tables

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to create filtered Pivot tables using a loop according to the quantity of countries in the database.

For example:

If I have 3 countries in a Database (Ecuador, Brazil, Colombia), the macro will create 3 Pivot Tables side by side filtered with each country.

If I have 4 countries in a Database, the macro will creat 4 Pivot Tables side by side filtered with each country.

and so on

Someone know how can I do that?

Comment: Please paste the code you are trying into the question and describe how it does and does not meet your expectations.

Comment: I would also recommend you look into VBA as that would be the best option for doing something like this.